# A Fun $L^2$ Inequality?

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, lp-spaces

I'm having trouble with a step in a paper which I believe boils down to the following inequality:
$$
\left\| \sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}} f(\cdot+k) \right\|_{L^2(0,1)}
     \leq c \|f\|_{L^2(\mathbb{R})}.
$$
I haven't come up with many ideas. Hitting the left-hand side with Minkowski, for example, produces something which can exceed $\|f\|_{L^2(\mathbb{R})}$.

I also put a bit of effort this afternoon into falsifying the above inequality (it may be that I'm misunderstanding the omitted steps in the original paper). Begin with a power series $g(x)=\sum a_kx^k$ which has a local $L^2$ singularity. It's then not too hard to use this representation to construct $f$ satisfying
$$
\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}} f(x+k) = g(x).
$$
However, the few times I attempted this did not result in an $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ function.

Any help one way or the other is appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you actually want the Poisson Summation formula? http://www.math.umn.edu/~garrett/m/mfms/notes_2013-14/02a_Poisson_summation.pdf

Comment: Good suggestion, but actually the expression on the left hand side *arises from* the Poisson summation formula! The paper states without proof something which looks like what I've posted, the main point being the infinite summation disappears.

Comment: Inequality (9.A.3) on p. 209: https://books.google.ch/books?id=SVcY3L_SZYEC&lpg=PP1&dq=mathematical%20aspects%20of%20dispersive%20equations&hl=en&pg=PA209

Comment: thanks for the book, may be useful to me actually :) the book assumes more than $f∈ L^2(\Bbb R^n)$...is that enough to ensure LHS is finite? I only dare apply Poisson summation to Schwartz functions in the first place.

Comment: For future reference, one can prove (9.A.3) using the weighted inequality I provide below. However, removing the weight from $\|\langle\cdot\rangle^\alpha [J^s;f]g\|_{L^2(\mathbb{R})}$ requires some facts about $J^s$ which are only alluded to on the next page. In particular for compactly supported functions $g$, then $J^sg$ is smooth and decays outside the support of $g$ (as $J$ has a nice integral representation in these regions). See Stein's *Harmonic Analysis*.

Comment: Thanks! This was an interesting question even if I did run around in circles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The inequality is not true: counterexample:

$$f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac 1n \chi_{[n, n+1]}.$$

Then $f\in L^2(\mathbb R)$, but

$$g(x):= \sum_{k\in \mathbb Z} f(\cdot + k) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac 1n = \infty$$

is not in $L^2(0,1)$.

Comment: Dang I thought I considered something like that! Thanks for the quick counterexample!

Answer (score 1):

The counterexample from Artic Char suggested that the statement is true with weight added:
\begin{align}
\left\| \sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}} f(\cdot+k) \right\|_{L^2(0,1)}
     &\leq \sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}} \|f\|_{L^2(k,k+1)} \\\\
     &= \sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}} \left(\int_k^{k+1} \left|\frac{1+x^2}{1+x^2} \cdot f(x)\right|^2\right)^{1/2} \\\\
     &\leq \sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}} \frac{1}{1+k^2} \|(1+x^2) \, f(x)\|_{L^2(k,k+1)} \\\\
     &\leq c \, \|(1+x^2) \, f(x)\|_{L^2(\mathbb{R})}.
\end{align}
Or, you could choose weight $|x|^\alpha$ for any $\alpha>1$.

Answer (score 0):

Inspiration from the Shannon sampling theorem: if you assume $\mathcal F_{\Bbb R} f$ is Schwartz with $\text{supp}\ f$ contained in $(-1/2,1/2)$ then  $$ LHS^2 = \sum_k |\mathcal F_{\Bbb R}f(k)|^2 = \sum_k \int_{\Bbb R} f(y) e^{-2\pi i ky} \ \text dy = \sum_k ∫_{-1/2}^{1/2} f(y) e^{-2\pi i ky} \ \text dy =  \sum_k |\mathcal F_{\Bbb T}\tilde f(k)|^2 = ‖\tilde f‖^2_{L^2(\mathbb T)}= ‖f‖^2_{L^2(-1/2,1/2)} = ‖f‖_{L^2(\Bbb R)}^2 $$
The first equality is Poisson summation, $\sum_k f(x+k) = \sum_k \mathcal F_\Bbb R f(k) e^{-2\pi i k x}$. Also, $\tilde f ∈ C^∞ (\Bbb T)$ is the 1-periodic extension of $f∈ C_c^∞(-1/2,1/2) $.

Unfortunately the assumption on the support of $f$ means that there is only one summand in LHS. I'll just leave this here anyway.

Comment: If you're compactly supported, then you can apply Minkowski like in my other answer. Then you conclude with a constant depending on the finitely many terms. It's a general principle that by assuming the function is in a weighted norm, one can make the constant independent of the number of terms.